# Square the sorted array using haskell

Tags: haskell

I want inputs on how I can square the sorted Array more efficiently in haskell. I wrote a very naive algorithm to solve the problem. What I am doing is comparing the head and the last element of list on absolute value and whichever is max I square the element and add it to accumulator.

But I think it is very slow. Is there any data structure that I can use to make it more efficient.

```
import qualified Data.List as List

sqrarr:: [Int] -> [Int]
sqrarr xss = helper  xss []


helper::[Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
helper  [] acc = acc
helper [x] acc = [(x^ 2)] ++ acc
helper (x:xss) acc = case abs x > abs (List.last xss) of
  False -> helper (x: (List.init xss)) (((List.last xss)^2): acc)
  True -> helper xss ((x ^ 2):acc)
```

The above code works and gives the desired input

```
sqrarr [-7, -4, 2,5,8]
[4,16,25,49,64]
```

I have found another solution

```
import Data.Array
sqrarr2::[Int] -> [Int]
sqrarr2 xss = helper2 0 (length xss -1)
                (listArray (0,(length xss -1)) xss)
                []


helper2::Int -> Int -> Array Int Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
helper2 l r arr acc = case l > r of
  True -> acc
  False -> case abs (arr!l) > abs (arr!r) of
    False -> helper2 l (r - 1) arr ((arr!r ^ 2):acc)
    True -> helper2 (l + 1) r arr ((arr!l ^ 2):acc)
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks needlessly convoluted: there is a lot happening, all at once, on top of each other.

The way to think about this is: first square each number, then sort the resulting list. The way to transform each element of a list is [`map`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-15.1/base-4.13.0.0/Prelude.html#v:map). The way to sort is, well, [`sort`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-15.1/base-4.13.0.0/Data-List.html#v:sort). The way to compose two functions (i.e. pass the result of one as argument to the other) is [`.` (dot)](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-15.1/base-4.13.0.0/Prelude.html#v:.)

So:

```
sqrarr = sort . map sq
  where
    sq x = x * x
```